# Стоит ли учить книгу 2008 года?

Tags: jquery, книги

Здравствуйте, хочу прочесть книгу [jQuery. Подробное руководство по продвинутому JavaScript](http://www.books.ru/books/jquery-podrobnoe-rukovodstvo-po-prodvinutomu-javascript-619339/), но она 2008 года. Подскажите, стоит ли её учить? Или посоветуете что либо посвежее? Спасибо.

Comment: Не вижу смысла учить jquery по книге, по моему - документация лучше.

Что касается различных туториалов и т.д - в интернете их огромное множество.

Тем не менее - когда-то давно листал эту книгу ( уже зная jquery ) - ничего толкового в ней не нашел ( возможно если бы я не знал jquery, она бы мне и понравилась, не знаю ), но, тем не менее, больше методов и подходов, с того времени, не изменились, соответственно - если вам больше нравиться книга, то можете читать. Тем более - от чтения документации это вас не спасает ( ни эта книга, ни любая другая ).

Comment: прочесть можно, учить - не стоит

Comment: @Spectre - '... хочу прочесть книгу ...' как-бы намекает :)

Comment: не ну понятно 400 страниц учить никто не будет) да и прочесть хочется так что бы был толк, если документации/туториалы более эффективны то спасибо за направление.

Comment: что значит 400 страниц никто учить не будет??? Троелсен (С#) 1400 и ниче норм, а тут жалки 400 страниц. А вообще, что бы быть в теме, нужно учить английский и читать всю литературу в оригинале, т.к. переводы выходят с оооогромным запозданием и не в очень хорошем качестве. 

По сабжу, если и делать что то с книгой 2008 года, то только читать для расширения кругозора.

Comment: @Jetu, вы знаете наизусть книгу Троелсона?

Comment: XD учить не значит вызубрить на зубок) учеба и зубрежка это совсем разные вещи, я не знаю эту книгу наизусть, но примерно помню, где, что и как, т.е. если мне нужно, я спокойно найду в ней то, что хотел (без оглавления).

Comment: Не надо ничего учить, вы не на экзамене же будете сдавать, никто не запрещает пользоваться документацией. Книга нужна для понимания основ и принципов работы.

Answer (score 3):

Я бы вообще не стал читать эту книгу.

Намного полезнее будет почитать книгу по базовому JavaScript. [JavaScript: Подробное руководство (Definitive Guide)](http://javascript.ru/book/definitiveguide).

Поверьте на слово, в `jQuery` вы разберетесь за 15 минут.

Answer (score 0):

2008 год - ну и что? Разберетесь в основах, которые там явно есть, а во всех наворотах, что появились к 2012 году разобраться будет уже очень просто.

Comment: Какие основы могут быть в книге по jquery? Все основы этой библиотеки помещаются в одит абзац, а большинство "магии" приписываемой jquery это обычный javascript.